# Regex not working for replacing special characters

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace special characters with nothing. So i tried

```
this.name.replace("[^a-zA-Z]+", "").trim()
```

I wnat the below word to be 000 Vektor

OOO "Vektor"

Comment: `this.name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "").trim()`

Comment: replace should accept[t string as first argumenet not regex.

Comment: already tried and not working

Comment: to add on @AvinashRaj comment, `String#replace` doesn´t use regex, just the plain literal

Comment: @Luxy can't reproduce..

Comment: how can i use regex in my code?

Comment: somehow your `OOO` are just regular `O`´s, which is why it doesn´t get replaced (no special char here, atleast for me)

Comment: nah nah i am talking about the "Vector"

Answer (score 4):

The documentation of `replace` says:

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified **literal replacement sequence**.

It won't take regular expressions.

The documentation of `replaceAll` says:

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given **regular expression** with the given replacement.

So you may use:

```
this.name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "").trim();
```

You may also use `replaceFirst` with regular expressions, though not here.

---

Also, in a comment you say that you have tried it. I suspect that it is because you just use :

```
this.name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "").trim();
```

But java Strings are **immutable**, and don't change by themselves.
Hence you should use:

```
this.name = this.name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "").trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.replace` takes a literal first argument. `replaceAll` uses a regex

```
name = name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]+", "");
```